# url-to-image renders every URL I try except the one I need

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web, phantomjs

I'm trying to implement the apparently useful and powerful [url-to-image module](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/url-to-image). Using the basic example script, I can render and save as a .png any website I try except the one I need, which uses angular.

I need something past the login page, but I can't even render the login page: http://momentum-leaderboard.herokuapp.com/#/login.

Any ideas on how to make this module work for this URL? Or ideas on another tool to render an image of a page such as this?

Answer (score 1):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) alone can solve this issue.  This script should be enough to render this login page: rasterizeSimple.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output, size;

if (system.args.length != 3) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };

    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit(1);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                page.render(output);
                phantom.exit();
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Getting past the login screen is another story.  Since PhantomJS is a web browser, lets just open the login page, fill out the form, press the login button, wait a couple seconds and then re-call the url of interest, now as a logged-in user.  Logging into the form can be done different ways, if you prefer, you can inject jquery.  Didn't test this second script, but it should get you going.

```
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (page.injectJs('jquery-1.11.2.js')) { // Loads from the working dir i think
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('Unable to load the address!');
                phantom.exit(1);
            } else {
                page.evaluate(function() {
                    $('input[name=username]').val('username');
                    $('input[name=password]').val('password123');
                    $('input[name=submit]').click();
                });

                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    page.open(address, function (status) {
                        if (status == 'success') {
                            window.setTimeout(function () {
                                page.render(output);
                                phantom.exit();
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    });
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response, but this is still rendering a blank pdf, same as the other modules as libraries I've tried. Is it working for you? If so, what OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 10.  Just to trouble shoot, you can access it from another web browser from the same computer?  Does the command line running phantomjs have admin privileges?

Comment: Yes, I can access this login page from the same computer or any device. I am running from a command line with admin privileges. I've tried on OSX and Windows 8, and consistently get a blank pdf for this one and only page. Just to be clear, you are rendering this specific login page with this first script on a Windows 10 OS? Thanks again, I really appreciate your insight.

Comment: Yes, this script managed to render the login page.  At first it did not render as expected, then I increased the timeout for the render to 2000 and it worked.  Does it take a long time to load?  Remember PhantomJS wont know if everything is loaded on the page easily, but you can usually just wait a few seconds to ensure all resources loaded.

Comment: Also try to print out the status from `page.open(address, function (status) { ... });` to confirm you are not having HTTP errors.